# How to set the base SDK when i want my app support iOS6

Tags: ios

I want my app to support iOS 6. So I set the Base SDK to iOS 6 and the deployment target is iOS 6 also. But when I build my project, the compiler complains that some macros in the project which is iOS 6 compatible are not defined. Such as __IPHONE_6_1.

Should I should change the Base SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to change the deployment target for it to work.

Comment: Thank you ! Did you mean I just change the deployment target and not need change the base sdk. For example if i want to make my app iOS 6 compatible, i just change deployment target to ios6 , and base sdk > = ios6 (maybe iOS 7 iOS 8 )